# How does a person participate more if they cannot make comments?

Tags: discussion

I do not feel qualified from a science point of view to answer questions specifically. My opinions are opinions only, but I do not have enough points to make comments.

The people here have been extraordinarily helpful and I'd like to participate more, but again, I have a lack of science education to back up my answers.
I want to thank everyone for their help and I will try to participate... but it isn't easy!

How does a person participate more if they cannot make comments?

Comment: You get points for copyediting. Fix typos, tablet fingers, and goofy punctuation.

Comment: Also note that quite a few of the questions you have answered have been closed as off topic. In general answers on closed questions get far fewer votes and views than ones on open questions (and additionally answering the questions encourages asking of off-topic questions). It's worth checking for existing close votes before starting to write an answer.

Comment: @TimB: But users with less than 3000 rep can't see close votes.

Comment: I've been in ur shoes and it was terrible at first, I just started learning English from YouTube and not only I couldn't rectify other works I also had great difficulty posting questions. Now I feel terrific and it becomes a chore to comment whenever I want it wherever I want it...

Comment: It is getting easier. I am more used to forums where there can be conversation drift, off-topic comments and so on. It takes getting used to, but I really like it, too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not all questions require scientific knowledge. I find that common sense, and a smattering of random facts go a long way on Worldbuilding.

The only thing I can recommend is to keep an eye out, and take a stab at answering. Even if your answer is not the *best*, you will still gain rep.

Keep in mind that commends do not gain you rep, and that the more you participate, the more you will have access to other exciting ways in which to interact with the community (chat, edit review, voting to close/open, etc.)

Last but not least, ask a question! You'll gain votes, and help others by leaving an interesting topic behind for Worldbuilders to come!

Comment: thanks, that is what I'll do. I just feel like I can't contribute very much.

Comment: @willowrex - it all comes with time. By reading through WB posts you'll gain valuable info which you can then use to answer other questions. I strongly recommend taking a look at how to format your posts on SE as well. A well-formatted post always gets more attention than a wall of text, etc.

Comment: thanks again, I appreciate it.

Comment: Try looking for more politically- or historically-oriented questions.

Comment: I find that logical thinking, with a good amount of reading sci-fi/fantasy can already make me participate and engaged with this community. Real scientific knowledge is great but it is not the only solution to participate. Just need to try hard and think through to answer.

Comment: I want to ask real questions. Things I do not know about or understand but need to know. I could ask fake questions, but will refrain. ;)

Answer (score 10):

The reputation access levels are there to make sure you have some time to learn about the site before you start getting access to the tools. For example learning which questions should be closed, edited, opened is something that experienced users still have debates about to this day.

If you stay active writing answers and questions and reading the site then over time your reputation will increase and you will get access to more and more tools. You can already join the chat room, soon you will be able to add comments.

You should already be able to edit posts, removing typos. Cleaning up English, improving formatting. Be careful not to change the meaning of posts but we can all help make the posts as good as they can be.

As your reputation increases you will then get access to the review queues, which is your next chance to contribute. Checking whether questions should be open or closed, checking whether edits are appropriate, etc.

This site is run by the community, for the community. We ease people in gradually but welcome to your first steps :)

Comment: Thanks it seems to be working. However, there are things I don't understand -- yet. I think down-voting on answers is weird because it is anonymous. If you don't like an answer, make a comment. It teaches more than some perhaps just nasty person down-voting. Also, I can't up-vote my answers, but I assume I could down-vote everyone else's? If down-voting on answers was not anonymous, I'd get it. Questions are different, though obviously any question or answer that gets no votes would fall to the bottom. I hope to come to a better understanding soon

Comment: It costs reputation  to down vote answers. A pattern of down voting everyone else regularly would be spotted too...

Comment: thank you, I missed that part. It makes more sense.

Comment: your comments have been very helpful.